# Why recv() hangs?

Tags: sockets, tcp, ip

I'm using socket programming now, the process is as follows:

> Client-------Get username from scanf()------Send
> username---------Server
>
> Server-------Send acknowledgement message-------Client
>
> Client------Get acknowledgement-----Get password from scanf()------Send password----------Server
>
> Server-------Get password

But i got server hangs at the second recv(), i googled it and the only answer about it is the read boundary problem, but for username, i did tell server how much bytes it should get...Can't figure about what' going on...

Code Client:

```
    printf("Please enter the username: ");

    scanf("%s", username); 

    //send username

    datalen = strlen(username);

    temp = htonl(datalen);   

    send(simpleSocket, (char*)&temp, sizeof(datalen),0); 

    bytes_sent = send(simpleSocket, (char*)&username, datalen,0);

    //waiting acknowledge
    bytes_recv = recv(simpleSocket, (char*)&acknowledge,sizeof(acknowledge), 0);    

    if(bytes_recv > 0){
        printf("Got Acknowledge!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Didn't Get Acknowledge!\n");
    }

    //if get acknowledge, get password
    if(bytes_recv > 0){

    printf("Please enter the password: ");        
    scanf("%s", password);

    //send password
    datalen = strlen(password);
    temp = htonl(datalen);
    bytes_sent = send(simpleSocket, (char*)&temp, sizeof(datalen),0); 

    bytes_sent = send(simpleSocket, (char*)&password, datalen, 0);
    printf("Bytes_sent(password): %d\n", bytes_sent);
}
```

Code Server:

```
int buflen = 0;

bytes_recv = recv(simpleChildSocket, (char*)&buflen, sizeof(int), 0);

buflen = ntohl(buflen);

//printf("%d\n", buflen);

bytes_recv = recv(simpleChildSocket, username, buflen, 0);

if(bytes_recv > 0){

    printf("Sent Acknowledge!\n");
    char acknowledge[256] = "Have Gotten Username!";  
    bytes_sent = send(simpleChildSocket, acknowledge,strlen(acknowledge),0);

    index = CheckUsername(username);
    printf("Index at: %d\n", index);

}

else{
    printf("Didn't receive username!\n");
    close(simpleChildSocket);
}



//read password

bytes_recv = recv(simpleChildSocket, (char*)&buflen, sizeof(int), 0);

buflen = ntohl(buflen);

bytes_recv = recv(simpleSocket, password, buflen, 0);

if(bytes_recv > 0){

    printf("Bytes_recv(password): %d\n", bytes_recv);

    if(password == PASSWORD[index]){

        printf("Match Success!\n");

    }

}

else{

    printf("Didn't Get Password!");

    close(simpleChildSocket);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that one send equals one receive, and that every receive fills the buffer provided. It ain't necessarily so. See the documentation. The only guarantee with receiving in blocking mode is that at least one byte is transferred, unless end of stream or an error occurred.